# why am I getting 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)' after upgrading from rails 2.0 to rails 2.3.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is happening in an after_save method in one of my models, PlayerAction. I didn't change any code during the upgrade (famous last words). It appears to be happening on the following line:

```
if self.action_type.id == 1
```

The PlayerAction model has a

```
belongs_to :action_type
```

Changing action_type.id to action_type_id fixed that problem, but the same problem is happening in another place, in this line

```
player_action.action_type.desc
```

Here is the full stack trace, where the problem is occurring in that line

```
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:49:in `find'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:49:in `send'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:49:in `find_target'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:240:in `load_target'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:112:in `reload'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1219:in `action_type'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/models/game.rb:164:in `full_xml'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/models/game.rb:160:in `each'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/models/game.rb:160:in `full_xml'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/models/game.rb:156:in `full_xml'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/models/game.rb:136:in `full_xml'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/models/game.rb:86:in `full_xml'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/controllers/games_controller.rb:33:in `show'
C:/InstantRails2-0/rails_apps/rftg/app/controllers/games_controller.rb:30:in `show'
```

ActionType is another model of mine, and is a pretty generic name, as pointed out in another answer.  Could that be the source of the problem?  I looked in the main rails framework docs and didn't see a class or method named ActionType or action_type.

Turns out I did just add a custom find method for ActionType:

```
def self.find(id)
  Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) { ActionType.find(id) }
end
```

ActionType is basically static data and I'm trying to cache it. There are about 10 rows for ActionType, and I have several other models that have similar static data. That's the whole reason I started the process to upgrade rails, to get that caching functionality. I've been trying to find an example of how to do this correctly.  Clearly the above code isn't correct. I found another question here about the best-practice way to handle static data in a model, but it didn't quite help.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?  `action_type` is rather generic, perhaps it's colliding with a rails method.

Answer (score 2):

try it with

```
if self.action_type_id == 1
```

At least you'll know if that's the problem.

Okay, seeing that that is a problem, per comments, the line in Rails it's dying on is in here:

```
def find_target
      find_method = if @reflection.options[:primary_key]
                      "find_by_#{@reflection.options[:primary_key]}"
                    else
                      "find"
                    end
      @reflection.klass.send(find_method,
        @owner[@reflection.primary_key_name],
        :select => @reflection.options[:select],
        :conditions => conditions,
        :include => @reflection.options[:include],
        :readonly => @reflection.options[:readonly]
      ) if @owner[@reflection.primary_key_name]
    end
```

I am assuming you are using "id" for the primary key, because it is dying in the find method which is reflectively invoked. Of course, that method takes (*args), so shouldn't be dying on the 2 for 1 problem...

So, a) have you defined some custom finder for this class (finder_sql?)

b) what is the full_xml method that this is in? Is that just the part where you call

```
 player_action.action_type.desc
```

?

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks! But can you tell me why?

Comment: I think I'd have to see the stack trace to hazard a guess.

Comment: I added the stack trace as well as another place where the same error is happening

Comment: Yes, full_xml is the method where the player_action.action_type.desc line is. I do not have a custom find method for this class.  However, I am doing a PlayerAction.find() where I have includes and conditions arguments, and I just realized that ActionType is not in the include list.

Comment: It should be in there to prevent running the query too many times, but that shouldn't be causing the error.

Comment: Strike my last comment, I completely forgot that I did just add a custom find method for ActionType. See the details in the answer.